# Facebook App <title> iframe

Tags: php, iframe

FB does not parse `<title>` from the my application. Can we effect browser window title when FB displays our application?

Answer (score 0):

Are you working on an iFrame application?

As far as I know the only way to change the title of the application is to change it in the application settings (changing the application name).

Edit:

just did a bit of googling and it seems you can use `<fb:title>My title</fb:title>` on fbml applications

Comment: `FBML` is deprecated as far as I know. Any other way to do it?

Comment: Have you tried setting it with javascript using     document.title = 'test';? I will try it myself in a second but not sure if it works.

Comment: nope doesn't seem to work. As far as I know there is no way to set the title of an iFrame application other than changing the app name. If somebody knows a way would be great to hear it.